# Ganglia installations fails in centos7 (rrd_create in -lrrd... no)

Tags: centos, centos7, rrdtool, rrd, ganglia

When i try to install ganglia in centos7, I am getting following error

```
Configuring libmetrics ...

checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... yes
checking for pthread_create in -lpthreads... no
checking rrd.h usability... yes
checking rrd.h presence... yes
checking for rrd.h... yes
checking for rrd_create in -lrrd... no
Trying harder by including the X library path
checking for rrd_create in -lrrd... no
```

But I have rrd tool already installed

```
rrdtool -v
RRDtool 1.4.8  Copyright 1997-2013 by Tobias Oetiker <tobi@oetiker.ch>
           Compiled Nov 20 2015 19:23:48
```

configure command: 
    ./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib64" --build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --program-prefix= --disable-dependency-tracking --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --sysconfdir=/etc --datadir=/usr/share --includedir=/usr/include --libdir=/usr/lib64 --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --localstatedir=/var --sharedstatedir=/var/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man       --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-gmetad --enable-status --sysconfdir=/etc/ganglia

Answer:

On looking at config.log file we see

```
/usr/lib64/libEGL.so.1: undefined reference to `drmFreeDevice'
```

symbols of libEGL.so are not available. hence did update which fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

sudo yum -y update -- fixed the issue

Comment: This may very well fix the issue stated - however this does not really reveal anything about the nature of the problem or how it fixes it. please help the questioner (and by nature everyone else) by looking further into why the library is not being found.

Comment: Thanks. i updated which library was missing. Not sure why its missing symbols

Comment: When I referred to questioner, I assumed a different person, I laughed internally when I realised I was asking you to help yourself :P, additionally, Some of the updates to your question may better be suited to the answer instead, like the last line. I'll delete this comment if you do that so it doesn't look like I'm nagging :)